# Centos 7 - Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-27.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)

Tags: php, unix, centos, digital-ocean

I got this problem when I try to install `php-gd.x86_64` library.

```
sudo yum install php-gd.x86_64
```

Then I got this error message.

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-27.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.2
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.1
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: It looks like you've installed php 5.4 from a nonstandard repo that does a bad thing by naming the package simply 'php' instead of something like 'php54'. This custom repo doesn't seem to offer a php-gd package, and the only php-gd's your system *can* find are from repos that only offer 5.3. You've dug yourself a nice hole, I suggest posting on http://superuser.com as this is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the php-common package from the remi repository installed. That is a version newer than what is in CentOS 7. The CentOS 7 package of php-gd requires the CentOS 7 php-common package and not the remi version of php-common.

You can either see if the remi repository has a php-gd package (though I imagine that might have shown up already if it did) or you can remove the remi php-common (and presumably a number of other packages from that repo) and install the CenOS 7 php-common (and associated) packages.

Alternatively, you could try to rebuild the CentOS 7 php-gd source rpm against the version of php you have installed.